# A whole bunch of JButtons

Tags: java, swing, awt

Please review this code.

```
  import java.awt.*;

 import javax.swing.*;
 public class Snake_Ladder  {
public static void main(String[] args) {
new Snake_Ladder();
}

public Snake_Ladder(){
int i;
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel pane = new JPanel();
GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(11,0);
        pane.setLayout(experimentLayout);
        for(i=100;i>=91;i--){
        pane.add(new JButton(" " +i));
        }
        for(i=81;i<=90;i++){
        pane.add(new JButton(" " +i));
       }
        for(i=80;i>=71;i--){
        pane.add(new JButton(" " +i));
        }
        for(i=61;i<=70;i++){
        pane.add(new JButton(" " +i));
        }
        for(i=60;i>=51;i--){
        pane.add(new JButton(" " +i));
        }
        for(i=41;i<=50;i++){
        pane.add(new JButton(" " +i));
        }
        for(i=40;i>=31;i--){
        pane.add(new JButton(" " +i));
        }
        for(i=21;i<=30;i++){
        pane.add(new JButton(" " +i));
        }
        for(i=20;i>=11;i--){
        pane.add(new JButton(" " +i));
        }
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
        pane.add(new JButton(" " +i));
        }
frame.add(pane);
frame.setSize(1200,1400);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

 }
```

Comment: Close voters: Even though this question is asking for some feature to be added (which is off-topic), the current code does work and really **needs** to be reviewed! I think we should review this without answering how to add the wanted feature!

Comment: Edited question to make it on-topic. (Sorry, I just had to)

Comment: We only review code here, we won't write code for you. Once you have figured out how to add background image you can come back and post a new question, with the suggestions you see below included.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately your question about "How to..." is off-topic for this site but I feel that your code really **needs** to be reviewed as there are some things that can be improved.

- **Don't import .*** Only use the imports that you need. If you need to import `JButton`, import `JButton`, don't import all other classes within the same package.
- Fix your indentation and spacing `for (i = 100; i >= 91; i--) {` is a lot more readable than what you currently have.

Also, use an extra indentation step (one tab / four spaces) after each `{` and go back one indentation step after each `}`. Applying this, your code will look like:

```
for (i = 61; i <= 70; i++) {
    pane.add(new JButton(" " + i));
}
```

To make your IDE do the indentation for you:

- If you are using Eclipse, select all your code and press either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.
- If you are using Netbeans, select all your code and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Update, your for-loop can be written as only one loop (even though it's quite many variables and this code possibly needs it's own review...)

```
int COUNT = 100;
int last10s = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
    int decreasing = COUNT - i;
    int even10 = i / 10;
    if (decreasing % 10 == 0)
        last10s = decreasing;
    boolean shouldDecrease = even10 % 2 == 0;
    int increasing = last10s - 9 + i % 10;
    int chosen = shouldDecrease ? decreasing : increasing;
    pane.add(new JButton(" " + chosen));
}
```

Comment: Simon, Why Should I import only JButtons not all other classes.

Comment: @SajalArora It will pollute your namespace, when you press `Ctrl + Space` if you are using an IDE, which I hope you are, you will see a whole lot of other classes that you're not using. I think of this as the main reason, but there are probably other good reasons as well.

Answer (score 4):

The vast majority of your code looks like this

```
for(i=20;i>=11;i--){
  pane.add(new JButton(" " +i));
}
for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
  pane.add(new JButton(" " +i));
}
```

The only differences are that values in the for loop. You should create a function that contains the repeated code.

```
void addButtonsUp(JPanel pane, int start, int stop) {
  for(i=start;i<=stop;i++){
    pane.add(new JButton(" " +i));
  }
}
void addButtonsDown(JPanel pane, int start, int stop) {
  for(i=start;i>=stop;i--){
    pane.add(new JButton(" " +i));
  }
}
```

This will cut the big block of 30 lines down to 10. It also makes the code more readable. I didn't realize that you were alternating between counting up and count down until I started working on my answer. When your eyes see a section of code that looks repetitive, your brain assumes that is the case and continues on. If there was a small bug in the 3rd for loop, it would not stand out. Moving the actual looping into a function means that the structure can only be wrong in one place.

However, just calling these methods directly can still be improved. There are a lot of [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) in the code. The values that specify the start and stop values are very structured, but there is nothing in the code to indicate that. What you can do is to use another loop to make the calls to `addButtonsUp()` and `addButtonsDown()`.

```
void createSnakeGrid(JPanel pane, int max, int min, int step) {
  for (int i = max; i > min; i+=step*2) {
    addButtonsDown(pane, i, i+step);
    addButtonsUp(pane, i+(step*2), i+step);
  }
}
```

And now you can call a single function that will construct the entire grid by passing in the values that matter (100, 1, -10). I did not extensively test `createSnakeGrid()`, so it might not be completely correct. But you should be able to get the intent from what is there.